# AD user export/import

Tags: powershell

I'd need help exporting all users from AD (2008r2+Exchange 2010) using
`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *`  in .csv.
I would obviously need to format as table.

Then , after few amendments, I would need to import .csv to another server ( 2016+Exchange 2016)
There are plenty of PS scripts available but I didn't find any which will export all properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all Properties, CSV is not the right format for this job, it will export many `[System.Object[]]` fields as some properties are an array objects.

The best option if you want to export and then import back is to use XML, it will save the structure of the data and will De-Serialize the data back when needed using `Import-Clixml`

So the answer is very simple, just pipe the results to `Export-CSV` or `Export-Clixml`

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Clixml C:\output.xml
```

Comment: XML would be difficult to interpret and edit. I need to change e-mail addresses few names and other details. What if I'll go for CSV way and remove unnecessary columns? Will I be able to import ? 
Another question -how ?